# Thread performance advice

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm making a music player and I came to the point where I want to load art covers for each song. Currently I have over 450 songs on my phone and my thread to fill the list takes about 53 seconds to complete the task. Is there any other way to do it quicker?

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

                MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetreiver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < baseSongList.size(); i++) {
                        try {
                            metaRetreiver.setDataSource(baseSongList.get(i).getPathID());
                            byte[] art = metaRetreiver.getEmbeddedPicture();
                            if (art != null) {
                                BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true; //just check size of image
                                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length, opt);
                                // assign values of image
                                int imageHeight = opt.outHeight;
                                int imageWidth = opt.outWidth;

                                //condition to determine max inSample size
                                if (imageHeight > 90 || imageWidth > 90) {
                                    final int halfHeight = imageHeight / 2;
                                    final int halfWidth = imageWidth / 2;
                                    int inSampleSize = 1;
                                    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= 90
                                            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= 90) {
                                        inSampleSize *= 2;
                                    }
                                    opt.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
                                }
                                opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                                Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length, opt);
                                baseSongList.get(i).setAlbumArt(songImage);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("ddd", "exception in cover");
                        }
                    }
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: why load everything at once? maybe only load the 10 at a time and load more as the user scrolls through their songs?

Comment: @JohnKane I load list before activity is reached just with null's in Bitmap parameter. Here i load covers when app is fully funcional and just update contents of that one field. Actually it works like you said, every second new images appear and that's strange since handler receives message only after all images are displayed not after each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `recyclerView` and then use a data binding adapter. In that way you can avoid loading all your songs in one go, thus improving the overall performance. To get much more superior performance you use open source libraries of the likes of [picasso](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library).

Hope this helps !!